# Leaving an alias in a group by statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

From time to time if I have used a `case` statement in my `select`, and then copy this into the `group by`, I leave the alias in by mistake.
The alias is essentially superfluous at this point, and is not allowed as it is incorrect syntax.
Why is this not allowed as I cannot see that it affects the overall output? Is it simply a design choice?

Comment: SQL has a standard and the standard does not allow defining aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  No database that I know of accepts that syntax, although some do allow the use of the alias itself in the `GROUP BY` (instead of the expression).

Answer (score 0):

This is because GROUP BY is executed first before SELECT, so the alias has not yet been defined so SQL doesn't know it yet. With this, you can already use alias in ORDER BY.

Please see the hierarchy of SQL execution below

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP